# HEROKU: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: sql-server, django, heroku

I am having an issue trying to use SQL Server with Pyobdc in Django on Heroku. I'm getting this error:

> ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65706671/edit) your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any chance to test it with less information but I guess it is related to connectivity configurations. You can read the issue [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/610), some of the users solved the problem by overriding the OpenSSL configuration. I'm not sure how you can handle this on Heroku. You can read the comments to learn how to get trace logs. They might help you to find the solution.

Comment: I've read that article and traced logs but I dont know how to fix this in Heroku...